# How can I migrate Android preferences with a new version?

Tags: android

I have an app where I'm storing user preferences like this:

```
public static final String KEY_PREFS_LOGIN_INFO = "login_info";
public static final String KEY_PREFS_FILE_VERSIONs = "file_versions";
public static final String KEY_PREFS_LOGS = "logs";
public static final String KEY_PREFS_OTHERS = "others";
```

With pref-specific methods like this:

```
public static void setFileVersion(String key) {
    SharedPreferences settings = getAppContext().getSharedPreferences(KEY_PREFS_FILE_VERSIONS, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putString("current", key);
    editor.commit();
}
```

and then retrieving the values like this:

```
public static String filesVersion() {
    SharedPreferences settings = getAppContext().getSharedPreferences(KEY_PREFS_FILE_VERSIONS, 0);
    String current = settings.getString("current", "");
    return current;
}
```

What I want to do is have all of my preferences be stored in one location, so I can use a generic method to access any of them. How can I set a way to, on upgrade, migrate values from the old storage locations to the new? I'm looking for something similar to the onUpgrade() method in a SQLiteOpenHelper.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would override Application. Then on start up check what version number is stored in your shared preferences, and then perform the traversal from any old keys to new keys as necessary.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    private static final int CURRENT_PREFS_VERSION = 2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        if(filesVersion() != CURRENT_PREFS_VERSION){
            migrate(filesVersion())
        }
    }

    private migrate(int oldVersion){

        switch(oldVersion){
            case 1:
                //get old preference, store new preference
                break;
        }

        setFileVersion(CURRENT_PREFS_VERSION)
    }
```

Comment: So I'm guessing that means that I have to keep around the old preference names, basically forever? But maybe I should remove the final variables and just put the strings directly in. What do you think?

Comment: To support migration from older versions of your app you'll have to keep the old names lying around somewhere. But your idea to centralise acccess to preferences is still a fair idea, one that I've used on apps I have released.

Comment: Okay, makes sense - I have one other problem with this, though - How can I get the old prefs version if I haven't been storing that already? Should I just, for this version, assume (correctly, of course) that I have to upgrade and only later add an if clause to check the version?

Comment: Well when you pull the version number, when it doesn't exist, it's zero, so assume it's version zero :)

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out :) Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Cornholio I think hard-coding is a fair game here, because the old names are deprecated and should never be used outside this small migration code. So any time you want to get rid of a preference, move its definition to this migrator, but keep the currently valid preferences as constants. I would also suggest a remove the old preference after the new value is written.

Comment: This only handles the migration from N-1 version. You should consider if user has not updated the app since last 3-4 migrations then you need to handle them as well so you should not break the condition and call method iteratively until migrate to latest version